# Linear regulator darlington

Tags: darlington

I don't know if such a regulator should be sinking current in the first place,
I can't get any example on the web that shows a similar example of an op amp sourcing current
to the base of the NPN to compensate for the error voltage between non inverting and inverting terminals.
I thought it was supposed to source current.

For example when the slider at potentiometer X1 is 50/50 the non inverting input says 2.5 V which is correct.
The same at the inverting input. But for some reason the op-amp needs to sink current to achieve this. LTSpice
says its sucking 2.4 mA from the NPN base at this point. Current from Vtest is 309 mA and current is 312 mA at the
emitter. (This is a simpler example)

[image]

Comment: But npn IE = IB + IC and IC = 309mA and IE = 312mA, which would be 309mA + 2.4mA = 311.4mA, which is 312mA if 309mA has rounding going on.  And where is the Darlington?

Comment: You should add a resistor between the base and the V+ power supply. Ib can't be "logically" "negative" ...

Answer (score 2):

Your circuit is a classic op-amp controlled current source. TIP41 is not the best transistor for the purpose, given its low gain - and it's not a Darlington. Instead, you can use a Sziklai pair of a PNP power transistor, and an NPN driver. For stability, the circuit needs to be compensated.

In the design below, the emitter resistor of Q1 provides local negative feedback around Q1. The rest of the stabilizing feedback is provided by C2. C1 suppresses start-up transients by ensuring that the setpoint voltage ramps up cleanly.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFWcz2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Instead of using a transistor, a mosfet would do nicely and provide faster transient response:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWWzux.png)</sup>

> I can't get any example on the web that shows a similar example of an op amp sourcing current to the base of the NPN

There's probably tens of thousands of such current source schematics out there... Not identical to yours, but within the general ballpark. I guess the problem was with not using the magic keywords needed. That is indeed often an obstacle for newcomers to any field.